# Website being spammed

Tags: bots

A client has a basic html website with a few pdfs on it.

The server is reporting 10gb in a day for downloads.

I have seen the IP / Visitor reports.  There are numerous downloads of the PDFs pushing the bandwidth up. I have blocked the IPs.

Is there anyway to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Captcha to allow download of the pdf.

Comment: There are 5 of them.  I will look into it though.

Comment: Thing is they can change their IPs

Comment: @user3398974 Please close the question if your problem is resolved!